# Atollic debug breakpoint problem STM32

Tags: truestudio, atollic

[image]

when we are debuging automatic breakpoint is coming near main.
how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try Run->Remove All Breakpoints. Atollic has the odd issue with random breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this behavior in **Debug Configurations**.

In the **Startup Scripts** tab there is a **Target Software Startup Script**. In the script is the line:

```
tbreak main
```

This line makes a temporary breakpoint at `main()`, which is removed when you continue running your code.

Remove this line to remove the breakpoint.